# How can I remove meta links from ResourceCollection response

Tags: laravel, resources

How can I remove links and meta from the response? I've not found needed method from here yet.
I think the following solution will be possible

***BeaterCollectionResource***

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class BeaterCollectionResource extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->transform(function($page){
                return [
                    '_id'   => $page->id,
                    'title' => $page->title,
                ];
            }),
        ];
    }

    public function withResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $jsonResponse = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        unset($jsonResponse['meta']['links']);
        $response->setContent(json_encode($jsonResponse));
    }
}
```

***Controller***

```
public function index(Request $request)  
{         
      $beaters = $this->_beaterRepo->list();         
      return new BeaterCollectionResource($beaters);     
}
```

***Response***

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "610b4992888d40554f6da2c2",
            "title": "Dane test",
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "http://beater.vm/api/v1/pet-recipes?status=3&page=1",
        "last": "http://beater.vm/api/v1/pet-recipes?status=3&page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "path": "http://beater.vm/api/v1/pet-recipes",
        "per_page": 10,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

That's the solution to remove the meta links in the response, I hope it helps everyone,

Comment: How did you use the `BeaterCollectionResource` Resource in your route?

Comment: I used in controller
`public function index(Request $request)
 {
        $beaters = $this->_beaterRepo->list();
        return new BeaterCollectionResource($beaters);
    }
`

Comment: Is `$beaters` a paginated object? Laravel will add those links by default if it is

Comment: @BenGooding
Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

`$beaters->items()` to get a collection rather than a pagination object

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and clever!

```
$data = $response->getData(true);

    if (isset($data['links'])) {
        unset($data['links']);
    }
    if (isset($data['meta'], $data['meta']['links'])) {
        unset($data['meta']['links']);
    }

    $response->setData($data);

    return $response;
```